# R: How to identify and label cluster groups in a dendrogram (created by hclust)?

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I have used hclust to identify clusters in my data, and determine the nature of those clusters. The following is a very simplified version:

```
gg <- c(1,2,4,3,3,15,16)
hh <- c(1,10,3,10,10,18,16)
z <- data.frame(gg,hh)
means <- apply(z,2,mean)
sds <- apply(z,2,sd)
nor <- scale(z,center=means,scale=sds) 
d <- dist(nor, method = "euclidean")
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward.D2")
plot(fit)
rect.hclust(fit, k=3, border="red")  
groups <- cutree(fit, k=3) 
aggregate(nor,list(groups),mean)
```

Using aggregate I can see that these three clusters include a cluster with low values on both gg and hh variables, a cluster with low gg and average hh, and a cluster with high gg and high hh values

How can I see where these are on the dendrogram (so far I can only tell by examining the sizes of the groups and comparing them to the sizes on the dendrogram)? And how can I somehow label those cluster groups on the dendrogram (eg add something like "low", "med", "high" names over each cluster)? I prefer answers in base R

Comment: Did you look at color_branches in dendextend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, without using the dendextend package, there are no simple options available for labeling. The closest bet is to to make use of the `border` argument in the `rect.hclust()` formula to color the rectangles... but that's no fun. Take a look at - http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/beautiful-dendrogram-visualizations-in-r-5-must-known-methods-unsupervised-machine-learning.

In this case with 2 columns I would recommend simply plotting the `z` data.frame and coloring or grouping visually by your `groups`. If you label the points, that would further make it comparable to the dendogram. See this example:

```
# your data
gg <- c(1,2,4,3,3,15,16)
hh <- c(1,10,3,10,10,18,16)
z <- data.frame(gg,hh)

# a fun visualization function
visualize_clusters <- function(z, nclusters = 3, 
                           groupcolors = c("blue", "black", "red"), 
                           groupshapes = c(16,17,18), 
                           scaled_axes = TRUE){
  nor <- scale(z) # already defualts to use the datasets mean, sd)
  d <- dist(nor, method = "euclidean")
  fit <<- hclust(d, method = "ward.D2") # saves fit to the environment too
  groups <- cutree(fit, k = nclusters) 

  if(scaled_axes) z <- nor
  n <- nrow(z)
  plot(z, main = "Visualize Clusters",
       xlim = range(z[,1]), ylim = range(z[,2]),
       pch = groupshapes[groups], col = groupcolors[groups])
  grid(3,3, col = "darkgray") # dividing the plot into a grid of low, medium and high
  text(z[,1], z[,2], 1:n, pos = 4)

  centroids <- aggregate(z, list(groups), mean)[,-1]
  points(centroids, cex = 1, pch = 8, col = groupcolors)
  for(i in 1:nclusters){
    segments(rep(centroids[i,1],n), rep(centroids[i,2],n), 
             z[groups==i,1], z[groups==i,2], 
             col = groupcolors[i])
  }
  legend("topleft", bty = "n", legend = paste("Cluster", 1:nclusters), 
         text.col = groupcolors, cex = .8)
}
```

Now we can plot them together:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
visualize_clusters(z, nclusters = 3, groupcolors = c("blue", "black", "red"))
plot(fit); rect.hclust(fit, 3, border = rev(c("blue", "black", "red")))
par(mfrow = c(1,1)
```

[image]

Make note of the grid for your eye-exam of low-low, low-med, high-high.

I love line segments. Try it on larger data like:

```
gg <- runif(30,1,20)
hh <- c(runif(10,5,10),runif(10,10,20),runif(10,1,5))
z <- data.frame(gg,hh)
visualize_clusters(z, nclusters = 3, groupcolors = c("blue", "black", "red"))
```

[image]

Hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have 3 variables that I'm using as cluster variables, but I appreciate your plots and may use them sometime in the future (I was making due with simple scatterplots comparing two variables at a time colored by group but I like how you have illustrated the central point of each group). I've decided to just change the border colors of rect.hclust as per your recomendation and add a legend. I suppose I dont really need to have R map the groups to the dendrogram - as I can figure it out from groups size - I just thought it would be cool.